# When resizing window, NULL_BRUSH become black

Tags: windows, winapi

*Platform: Windows 10.

IDE: Visual Studio 2022.*

I want to use a layered window to make a transparent background window. The code is as follows.

The window is transparent when it first appears, but after clicking on the Taskbar icon three times (or resizing the window), the window turns black, which is very strange.

**My question is, why does NULL_BRUSH suddenly fail, and how to remove the black background?**

It seems that the background of the window is not drawn entirely by the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message.

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK AppRegionProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain
(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR pCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX AppRegionData;
    AppRegionData.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    AppRegionData.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    AppRegionData.lpfnWndProc = AppRegionProc;
    AppRegionData.cbClsExtra = 0;
    AppRegionData.cbWndExtra = 0;
    AppRegionData.hInstance = hInstance;
    AppRegionData.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    AppRegionData.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    AppRegionData.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    AppRegionData.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    AppRegionData.lpszClassName = L"AppRegion";
    AppRegionData.hIconSm = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&AppRegionData)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"窗口类注册失败！", L"错误", MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    HWND AppRegionHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_LAYERED,
        L"AppRegion",
        L"窗口标题",
        WS_POPUP|WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        100,
        100,
        500,
        200,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
        AppRegionHandle,
        RGB(0, 0, 255),
        (BYTE)255,
        LWA_ALPHA
    );

    ShowWindow(AppRegionHandle, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(AppRegionHandle);
```

I have found very few similar problems on the Internet, but there is no clear cause and solution.

Comment: When you register a window class where `hbrBackground` is a `NULL_BRUSH`, your default `WM_ERASEBKGND` handling is essentially a no-op. What's wrong is hard to tell without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: When bAlpha is 255, the window is opaque. So the window does not show for some reasons.

Answer (score -1):

I figure out what's happenning.

Firstly, you used `WS_POPUP`. But the `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_POPUPWINDOW` styles must be combined to make the window menu visible. `WS_POPUPWINDOW` equivalent to `WS_POPUP`. Please refer to [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles).

Secondly, you set *bAlpha* to 255 in function `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`. **When bAlpha is 255, the window is opaque.** So it display a black window. Please set it between 1 and 254.

I modified the code. It shows normally.
[image]